# DialogFragment setMessage with a newLine

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to set some text into a DialogFragment, and this text contains some new lines.

I've tried all those:

`setMessage("This is line A \n This is line b");`

`setMessage("This is line A \\\n This is line b");`

`setMessage("This is line A+"System.getProperty("line.separator")"+This is line b");`

None worked.

Any tip?

Comment: My suggestion is to use a custom layout for your dialog using separate TextViews. You can check the official documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: Yea i know work arounds, but I'd like to know if this is possible :p

Comment: Let's say the workaround is the way you would like to use and not a custom layout :) Anyway, did you try to set your string as a resource like this?
<string name="title">Hello\nWorld!</string>

Answer (score 0):

You should set your string as a resource in the strings.xml file and then get it with the getString method.

Take a look here for more details: [String Resource new line /n not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a custom Layout for your Dialog or you could just use

```
String message = "First sentence \r\n Second sentence \r\n ..."
```