# How to get new line in String?

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to get Text from UTF-8 parsed text file, I am able to get the string properly but in that I have place line breaker \n which not working.

I am getting the whole string along with in between \n printed.

Getting my string using this code

```
solutionsView.setText(question.getAnswerS());
```

Comment: How did you try with `\n`? Please update question with example that you tried.

Comment: I have a text file in assets folder in that text file I have place \n.

Comment: then i parse this text file and retrieve data using above code.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible

Comment: suppose  question.getAnswerS() get string Hello\nWorld,but \n is not getting newline.

Comment: solutionsView.setInputType(getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);

Comment: try System.getProperty("line.separator"); or replace `\n` with `\\n`

Comment: How you parse your text file?