# Adding new lines in strings in XML files

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I'm trying to create a game but am currently facing an issue with rendering text from Strings.xml to a SurfaceView.

Example Strings:

```
<string name="somestring">Some String
              SOme more string</string>

<string name="somestring">Some String\nSOme more string</string>
```

The two above are the attempts I have tried, but it still shows up as single line when drawn on canvas using `canvas.drawText(getString(R.string.<resource>));`

How can I make it show as two lines, preferably without splitting the Strings?

Comment: try adding `android:lines="2"` to the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Things don't work same while drawing stuff on canvas in android!

**drawText()** twice with an offset **Y-position** to simulate a newline!

```
canvas.drawText("Some String", 100, 100, paint);
canvas.drawText("SOme more string", 100, 150, paint);
```

Comment: Yes, the \n should work ok on Android check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible)

Comment: \n works with raw code, but it doesn't appear to work with xml files

Answer (score 0):

¿Can you try this?

```
<string name="example">"Some string
        hey"</string>
```

The line break should work because the string is wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert but it ocurres me that you can use an special char like "-" in your xml file  and the replace it with java code with the "\n" char.

```
String somesTring = getString(R.string.<resource>).replace("-","\n");
```

Then use it in drawtext

This works if drawtext allows "\n" char.

Regards!