# How to change line of large string used as button name. I used &#10; to change line but it's not working. I given Image link. Any solution?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

[string.xml file screenshot of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEeI5.jpg)

[Design of app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCkG0.jpg)

Comment: Explain your problem in the question itself, not in the title. Ang give more details.

Comment: And don't use images in place of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Resource new line /n not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible)

Answer (score 0):

I used *\n* and it worked without any problem

```
<string name="example_new_line">First line\nSecond line</string>
```

hope it helps