# Add new line character in remote config text

Tags: android, newline, firebase-remote-config

I'm doing [**Firebase RemoteConfig**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) integration. In one of the scenarios, I need to break a text line, so I tried to use new line character (`\n`).

But this is not working, it is neither displaying as an extra character nor creating another line.

Comment: Did you tried `o&lt;br /&gt;` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5460289/996493)

Comment: @Lucifer after your suggestion tried that but not working :-/

Comment: @CoDe, did you find an answer for this?

Comment: nope, but fixing can be done with Mayank solution below.

Answer (score 13):

My solution is replace `\n` manually (assuming that in Firebase Console you put property for TITLE as "Title\nNewLine"):

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString(TITLE).replace("\\n", "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an uncommon character like two pipes || and then replacing every occurance of those with a newline after you do getString() in the code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just replace occurrences of `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

The trick (which actually works for all HTML tags supported on your target platform) is to wrap the String in a JSON Object on RemoteConfig, like so:

```
{
  "text":"Your text with linebreaks...<br><br>...as well as <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text.
}
```

On the target platform you then need to parse the JSON and convert it back to a simple string. On Android this looks like this:

```
// extract value from JSON
val text = JSONObject(remoteConfig.getString("remoteConfig_key")).getString("text")

// create Spanned and use it
view.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the suggestion mentioned above, you can try this code(that can be generalized to "n" number of elements). Simply replace the sample text with yours with the same format and add the amount of elements

```
String text="#Elemento1#Elemento2#Elemento3#";
int cantElementos=3;
arrayElementosFinales= new String[cantElementos];
int posicionNum0=0;
int posicionNum1;
int posicionNum2;

for(int i=0;i<cantElementos;i++){
    posicionNum1=text.indexOf("#",posicionNum0);
    posicionNum2=text.indexOf("#", posicionNum1+1);
    char [] m = new char[posicionNum2-posicionNum1-1];
    text.getChars(posicionNum1+1, posicionNum2,m,0);
    arrayElementosFinales[i]=String.valueOf(m);
    posicionNum0=posicionNum2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert encoded text(with Base64) to Firebase panel.

After, decode the String from your Java class and use it.

Like

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

So what worked for me is to use "||" (or some other character combination you are confident will not be in the string) as the new line character. Then replace "||" with "\n". This string will then display properly for me.

For some reason sending "\n" in the string doesn't get recognized as expected but adding it manually on the receiving side seems to work.

Answer (score -2):

Use Cdata in the remote config in combination with "br" tag and HTML.fromHtml() .. for eg.

```
<![CDATA[ line 1<br/>line 2]]>
```