# Android, new lines are not showed when reading from string resources?

Tags: android, string, newline

I have some texts in my `string.xml` file. When I set them in `textview`, new lines are not shown. 
So I copied the `string.xml` file from my project and pasted in my devices external storage and used a test app to read it as a text file. Surprisingly I could see the new lines present in the string I read from the file. So I don't know what the problem is!

Here there is no new line in the main app

[image: Here there is no new line in the main app]

Here the new line character is present in the string

[image: [Here the new line character is present in the string]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Resource new line /n not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible)

Comment: @ReazMurshed It is not a duplication. The questions are far different. Please compare the two again. Thanks