# Require 2 New Line in XML Android Strings?

Tags: android, string, textview, android-studio-3.0

For some reason, the only way a new line will show in the design tab of the phone on android studios is if I put `\n\n` instead of `\n` in my strings.xml file that is directly connected to the text component's text field.

If I just put `\n` it looks just as if nothing has ever changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Resource new line /n not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460256/string-resource-new-line-n-not-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I see now. I wanted there to be a visible new line between my paragraphs which was not showing. Essentially, I thought \n would make 2 lines. Thanks for the comment!